# Print or save protected PDF file

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

`PDF` file is opened in browser window, but I am unable to save or print it. Save option is hidden, but browser's built-in print function gives a blank page. I tried  to use `Chrome` extensions to save it automatically, but these aren't working. Screen capture extensions, like [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) creates screenshot only from the first page.

Comment: Can you open the protected file with a PDF Application?  We get protected PDFs from our Accountants and that is how we open them.

Comment: Hit Ctrl+S or select the save option for the link before opening the PDF.

Comment: @John : I can't download it.

Comment: Perhaps try a different browser and/or ask the source person of the document why you cannot download it.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install adobe accrobat. Because pdf file opens through pdf reader. Your pdf may have some restrictions like open password or purmission password for which you cant save it. 
Go to  the 'open file' menu and drag the pdf file that you want to open. Enter password to the 'open password' box.
For permission password go to the enable editing  option to remove the password protection. Open the ' protect' option and click ' password'. Unmark the ' permission password' option. Hope now you can save or print your protected pdf.